# C++ same name for non-virtual function in derived class conflicts with `final` specifier

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++14, crtp

This has the feeling of a complete newbie question, but why does the following code not compile when the `final` specifier is used for `B::operator()`?

```
struct A
{
    virtual void operator()() const = 0;
};

// the CRTP-component is not really necessary here
// but it possibly makes more sense in that it could be applied like this in reality
//
template<typename Derived>
struct B : A
{
    virtual void operator()() const override final
    {
        static_cast<Derived const&>(*this).operator()();
    }
};

struct C : B<C>
{
    void operator()() const
    {
        //do something
    }
};

int main()
{
    C()();
}
```

G++ prints the following [error message](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94534948be862a24):

```
main.cpp:17:14: error: virtual function 'virtual void C::operator()() const'
         void operator()() const
              ^
main.cpp:9:22: error: overriding final function 'void B<Derived>::operator()() const [with Derived = C]'
         virtual void operator()() const override final
                      ^
```

I would have thought it works as the non-virtual `C::operator()` does not override the virtual functions in its base classes? How can I bring this to work (--without changing the name of `C::operator()`)?

---

**EDIT**: As pointed out by several users, the answer is simply that the `virtual`-keyword in the derived class is redundant (whereas I thought leaving it out would prevent from inheriting). However, the goal I had in asking this -- namely **a consistent interface throughout the dynamic and static inheritance hierarchy** -- can be solved by using a non-virtual `operator[]` throughout and couple classes `A` and `B` by a virtual function `apply`:

```
struct A
{
    void operator()() const
    {
        this->apply();
    }

protected:
    virtual void apply() const = 0;
};

template<typename Derived>
struct B : A
{
    void operator()() const
    {
        static_cast<Derived const&>(*this).operator()();
    }

protected:
    virtual void apply() const override final
    {
        this->operator()();
    }
};

struct C : B<C>
{
    void operator()() const
    {
        //do something
    }
};

int main()
{
    C()();
}
```

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I was thinking `C::operator()` does only override when the `virtual`-keyword is used ... which is wrong as I learned today.

Comment: Oh, okay. I changed my answer, removing question about that. I guess the question now is how someone can have learned about references and `final` and `override` and `virtual` and `template`, and not about overrides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function in a derived class with the same signature as a virtual function in a base class overrides that virtual function from the base class. That makes it a virtual function, even if/though the declaration in the derived class doesn't use the `virtual` key word.

That can't be changed, so if you *really* need to have a function with the same name in a derived class that doesn't override the virtual function from the base class (and in the process, become virtual itself and in this case, violate the `final` in `B`) you'll need to change the signature of the function in the derived class. That can mean a different name, different parameter list, or different qualifiers. I'd treat the latter two with *extreme* caution though--the compiler will be able to sort out the mess you've made, but many human readers may (very easily) be surprised.

If I were reviewing such code, I'd probably cite this as a problem, and the author would need to provide very solid reasoning for why it was truly *necessary* to get it approved.

Comment: Thanks. I agree, changing the parameters and qualifiers is a mess. Still, that there is no way to prevent from overriding (maybe by simply dropping `virtual` as I incorrectly thought) is a bit unfortunate imo, as it means one cannot mix static- and dynamic-polymorphism using common function signatures throughout. But that might be subjective, as I use this pattern very often (and from now on hopefully more correct :-D)

Comment: My last statement isn't true. One can use a non-virtual `operator[]` throughout and couple the dynamically-connected ase and derived classes via an `apply-function. I make an edit in my original question.

Comment: @davidhigh: You *can* do this, but it strikes me as a design smell. The derived operators are hiding the base operator instead of overriding it, so if (for example) you call via a pointer to base, you'll get different behavior than you really want. Overall, the inheritance is saying "A `C` is an `A`", but now you're going back and saying, "but not *really* an `A`".

Comment: Thanks for your hints! So you would prefer the first variant in the OP with an `apply` function instead of `operator()` in the static-polymorphism branch? Still I can't figure out where exactly the second alternative is smelly (see also [this short FAQ entry](http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#redefining-nonvirtuals)) ... imo it satisfies the requirement that the client always sees the same behaviour (also when called via base class)...?

Comment: @davidhigh: I'd probably have to look at real code to be sure I understand what you're getting at, but my impression was that you were trying to get different behavior in C depending on whether you invoked it via a pointer/reference to A, or directly to an object of type C.

Comment: @JerryCoffin  I was under impression that once we set the virtual function as final, it cant be overridden any more in the child class, and we can have the same function name as a whole new function(an overload possibly), but realized taht the function name cant be used for any purpose in the child classes,meaning the name is forbidden to be used once it i final(obviously not as a override due to final key,but not even as a overload or as a whole new function), Correct me if iam wrong

Answer (score 7):

If a function is declared `virtual` in a base class, then a function declared with the same name and parameter list is implicitly `virtual` in derived classes, whether or not you use the `virtual` keyword. You cannot make `C::operator()()` non-virtual.

Answer (score 1):

As an override (because it has the same signature as the virtual function in a base class), the override conflicts with the `final` specified in its base class.

One fix (or rather workaround) is to give that function a defaulted argument, so that it has a different type and hence not an override, and a better approach is to fix the design.